# Calculating the nth result for itertools.product()

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations, python-itertools, combinatorics

I'm trying to calculate the nth result for itertools.product()

```
test = list(product('01', repeat=3))
print(test)

desired_output = test[0]
print(desired_output)
```

so instead of getting:

```
[('0', '0', '0'), ('0', '0', '1'), ('0', '1', '0'), ('0', '1', '1'), ('1', '0', '0'), ('1', '0', '1'), ('1', '1', '0'), ('1', '1', '1')]
```

I'm trying to get:

```
('0', '0', '0')
```

However as you probably already guessed, it doesn't scale well. Which is why I'm trying to only calculate the nth value.

I read through 
[Nth Combination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776442/nth-combination) but I'm in need of the repeat functionality that product() offers

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `repeat` functionality can be simulated quite easily. Here's a python version of the Ruby code described in [this](http://blog.sethladd.com/2010/03/calculating-nth-term-of-cartesian.html) blog post.

```
def product_nth(lists, num):
    res = []
    for a in lists:
        res.insert(0, a[num % len(a)])
        num //= len(a)

    return ''.join(res)
```

Call this function as

```
>>> repeats = 50
>>> chars = '01'
>>> product_nth([chars] * repeats, 12345673)
'00000000000000000000000000101111000110000101001001'
```

---

Here's some timeit tests:

```
repeat = 50
idx = 112345673

%timeit i = product_nth(['01'] * repeat, idx)
%%timeit
test = product('01', repeat=repeat)
one = islice(test, idx, idx+1)
j = ''.join(next(one))

2.01 s ± 22.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
36.5 µs ± 201 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

print(i == j)
True
```

---

The other answer is misleading because it misrepresents the functionality of `islice`. As an example, see:

```
def mygen(r):
    i = 0
    while i < r:
        print("Currently at", i)
        yield i
        i += 1

list(islice(mygen(1000), 10, 11))

# Currently at 0
# Currently at 1
# Currently at 2
# Currently at 3
# Currently at 4
# Currently at 5
# Currently at 6
# Currently at 7
# Currently at 8
# Currently at 9
# Currently at 10
# Out[1203]: [10]
```

`islice` will step through *every single iteration*, discarding results until the index specified. The same thing happens when slicing the output of `product`—the solution is inefficient for large N.

Answer (score 2):

If you build out the whole list if, of course, won't scale well because calling `list()` runs through the whole iterator.

If you only need the first value  you can just use `next(test)` to pull off the first value of the iterator. This doesn't require building the whole list and will be very fast.

You can use also `itertools.islice()` to get a specific part of the iterator without building out the whole list and it's quite fast. But understand that it will still iterate up to the the Nth value. This is a very pythonic way to do this, it's memory-efficient, and easy to read. Whether this is fast enough depends on how large your N needs to be. For example this produces a value of the 200000th combination quite quickly for me:

```
from itertools import product, islice

test = product('01', repeat=20)
one = islice(test, 200000, 200001)
print(''.join(next(one)))

# 00110000110101000000
```

Comment: @JacobW.Dallas This answer is misleading. The combination is indeed not generated instantly. `islice` generates, and discards everything upto the index specified. See some timeit tests in my answer.

Comment: @coldspeed aside from some hyperbole, this a good and very pythonic solution until the number of combinations is so big that it’s not. It certainly doesn’t deserve a downvote.

Comment: The solution is not inherently wrong, just with misleading language. The dv was for that.