# Combinations algorithm without enumeration

Tags: python, combinations, enumeration

here is how you generate combinations :

```
   from itertools import combinations_with_replacement, combinations
   list(combinations([1,2,3,4,5],r=3))
   [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 5), (1, 3, 4), (1, 3, 5), (1, 4, 5), (2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 5), (2, 4, 5), (3, 4, 5)]
```

Is there a way to get the Nth combination without enumerating all the previous items.

```
  combinations([1,2,3,4,5],r=3, nth=3)   ==>  (1,3,4)
```

The important thing is **not** to enumerate so that I can call for large numbers f.e.

```
  combinations(range(100),r=5, nth=3000000)   ==>  .....
```

I'm interested of the Algorithm/Source rather than callable function.

if it is possible at all, because I want to modify it for my needs

Comment: does this answer your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776442/nth-combination

Comment: Also if you can use `more_itertools` then you can use `more_itertools.nth_combination` this method is there.

Comment: @Mark you are correct. But in my first comment, there is already a discussion on this topic.

Comment: on first glance both seem like possible answers.. have to read through ... thanks